# Sorting categories in structures in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I have generated structures with more parameters, one of them is called 'category'. There are like 4 unique categories and then, they are duplicated. What I want to do is to save these 4 unique categories into string array, when I tried I saved all categories into array with a lot of duplicates.

```
void getCategories(financeStruct *financeData, unsigned int dataCount)
{
    string categ[dataCount];
    unsigned int i;
    bool doIt = true;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dataCount; i++){
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dataCount; j++){
            if (categ[j] == financeData[j].name)
                continue;
            else
                categ[i] = financeData[i].name;
    }
```

I want to have just these original categories in my array so when it find duplicate it won't write into array.

Comment: just use proper data type, `std::set` in this case

Comment: You just need to get the unique categories?  Of do you need to count the number of occurrences of each category?

Comment: Just save unique categories into array, with no duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string categ[4];
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < dataCount; j++)
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        if (categ[i] == financeData[j].name)
            break;  // Have it already
        else if ( categ[i] == "" ) {
            categ[i] = financeData[j].name;  // Checked all earlier ones without finding it
            break; }
```

This will store the first N categories encountered, as long as `N<=4`.  The strings in your array were all initialized to `""`, so the first `""` found while searching both indicates the next position that should be used and tells us we already searched all the used positions.  If we encounter too many categories, this code silently ignores the excess.

Comment: Did u mean i instead of j in the first if statement? If so it saves just the first category, not all as i want.

Comment: I made an edit ten minutes before your comment.  Are you asking about before or after that edit?  Before the edit, I was making a less plausible (after some thought) guess at what you are trying to do).  If you mean after that edit, I think you misunderstand the code.  If you misunderstand the code, you need to know `break` breaks the inner loop continuing the outer loop, which is why the outer loop must be across `financeData`.  Your original plan with outer loop over `categ[]` is harder to get right.

Comment: No, i commented before you edited, I tried new code and it works great. Many thanks to you.